# Remove white spaces at the right and left of the screen

Tags: html, css, padding

I am trying to remove the white spaces at the sides and make the image and text cover the entire width of the screen.

I have tried changing the flex basis values and adding the width in percentages, but it is not working. If I add the width in pixel units, then the image covers the space in between, but the white spaces on the sides do not go away.

[image: Website with unwanted white spaces]

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding-left: 8%;
  padding-right: 8%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.logo {
  width: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 30px 0;
}

.menu-icon {
  width: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
}

nav {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: right;
}

nav ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 30px;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
}

nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  color: gray;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0;
}

.col-1 {
  flex-basis: 30%;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.col-1 h2 {
  font-size: 54px;
}

.col-1 h3 {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #707070;
  font-weight: 100;
  margin: 20px 0 10px
}

.col-1 p {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #b7b7b7;
  font-weight: 100;
}

button {
  width: 140px;
  border: 0;
  padding: 12px 10px;
  outline: none;
  background: white;
  border: #000 solid 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: brown;
}

.col-1:after {
  content: "";
  width: 10px;
  height: 57%;
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  left: -40px;
  top: 8px;
}

.col-2 {
  flex-basis: 70%;
  display: flex;
}

.col-2 .controller {
  height: 530px;
  width: 100%;
}


/* .color-box{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    background: ;
    border-radius: 20px 0 0 20px;
    height:100%;
    width: 80%;
    z-index: -1;
    transform:translate(150px);
} */

.social-links img {
  height: 13px;
  margin: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

social-links {
  text-align: center;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:700px) {
  nav ul {
    width: 100%;
    background: white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 75px;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 2;
  }
  nav ul li {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
  nav ul li a {
    color: #000;
  }
  .menu-icon {
    display: block;
  }
  #menuList {
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
  }
  .row {
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
    margin: 50px 0;
  }
  .col-2 {
    flex-basis: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
  }
  .col-2 .controller {
    width: 77%;
  }
  .col-1 {
    flex-basis: 100%;
  }
  .col-1 h2 {
    font-size: 35px;
  }
  .col-1 h3 {
    font-size: 15px;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" class="logo" alt="logo">
      <nav>
        <ul id="menuList">
          <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Order</a></li>
          <li><a href="">About Us</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <img src="menu.png" class="menu-icon" alt="menu icon" onclick="togglemenu()">
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-1">
        <h2>We care for Your Dogs</h2>
        <h3>Give us a call to find out</h3>
        <p>this is a para</p>
        <button type="button">Read more</button>


      </div>
      <div class="col-2">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400" class="controller" alt="controller">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="social-links">
      <img src="fb.png" alt="">
      <img src="tw.png" alt="">
      <img src="ig.png" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    var menuList = document.getElementById("menuList");
    menuList.style.maxHeight = "0px";

    function togglemenu() {
      if (menuList.style.maxHeight == "0px") {
        menuList.style.maxHeight = "130px";
      } else {
        menuList.style.maxHeight = "0px";
      }
    }
  </script>

</body>
```

Comment: Have you used your browser's document inspector to [see what element has the whitespace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xADE0.png)? That's fundamental stuff for a web developer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have everything in a container and the container has left and right padding. Remove that from the container's CSS and it should work.